# python type function for dummy type

Tags: python-2.7

This is my first time to see the following codes.

```
dataset = type('dummy', (), {})()
```

And I print the dataset in the console it tells me that

```
<__main__.dummy at Ox7feec5195e90>
```

Can anyone help me to figure what these codes mean?

Comment: It creates class dynamically and creates instance of it right away. What's printed is a default string representation of custom class instance.

Comment: That helps, thank you. One more question, since this class is not declared by def class(object): ----what can I do if I want to have a class method to be used by this instance?

Comment: Pass it in the appropriate argument.

Answer (score 0):

`type` here is metaclass in python. The meaning of metaclass is that they create classes for us.

And the code above means that we create a class named `dummy`(the first parameter). The class does not inherit from any other classes, so the second parameter is `()`.The class does not have any attributes and methods, so the third parameter is `{}`.

If we want to create a class named `pp` including attribute `a` and method `m` and let the class inherited from class f, we can code like this:

```
class f():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def m():
    print (123)

metaclass = type("pp", (f,), {"a":33, "m":m})()
```